# Facebook Connect Issues

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've had the Facebook like button and comments (social plugin) on my website for a while, but for some reason, it just randomly disappeared. Nothing happens to the code, and the Facebook plugins aren't inserted. There's no errors in my JavaScript, and I haven't changed anything in that regard...

The weird thing is, if I go in my browser to Facebook.com, and then hit back, it will load fine. Once I refresh, it's gone again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/375287419165107/).

> Facebook JSSDK with locale en_US
>   (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) does not load but returns
>   "Not a valid locale."

What do you see at https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?

Comment: Ah yes! That does happen for me. So in other words, there's really nothing I can do?

Comment: If you're being affected by this bug, I don't believe there is anything you can do until facebook fixes the problem.